# Is it possible to change city size in SimCity?

Tags: simcity-2013

Is it possible to change city size in SimCity?  I heard many people complaining about being 2km x 2km, but don't know if somebody has done a trick or if Maxis is going to change it?

Comment: This is not possible.  The maps are not random they were not even generated by anything.

Comment: shame on the -1's without a comment.

Comment: thats what makes simcity 5 not very good then :( 2km is not funny

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm assuming they're because of the second part of the question if Maxis is going to change it. That'd be pure speculation at this point.

Comment: Add it to the list of lousy decisions EA/Maxis has made with regards to this game and move on.

Comment: The reason for the downvote is the fact the answer to this question was answered before the game was released in pretty much every SINGLE review of it.

Comment: @Ramhound I thought the policy of this site is to create an independent source of wisdom, that's why people are supposed to at least summarize a linked source in case the link goes dead. Also, the topic changed AFTER the game was released, as people started to mess with debugging mode.

Comment: @Ramhound lol you are very funny, do you think I had the time to read all that? thats why I came here to ask questions from polite people.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady - Unofficial hacks are not supported by EA.  People are also suppose to do research BEFORE asking a question.  I was asked the reason I issued a downvote to this question and I explained that reason.

Comment: @Ramhound support of EA is not relevant to the question, also I'm not agressive towards you, I just try to convince you that the question is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible to change the city size.

Comment: is it an upcoming change to this from EA?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, neither EA nor Maxis has said anything about changing this any time soon or ever -- and even if they did, speculation about what *might* be changed in a game is beyond the scope of this site.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot increase the city size and play on EA servers today.

---

[Creative Director Ocean Quigley](http://www.pcgamer.com/2013/03/01/simcity-city-size-maxis/) says SimCity’s team “could certainly make the city sizes larger” as a reaction to more powerful hardware setups.  ...  "We’ll eventually get around to expanding the city size, but I can’t make any promises as to when.”

---

Also, it's possible to [make a mod](http://metro.co.uk/2013/03/14/simcity-mod-allows-offline-play-3542102/) to enable debug mode.  This allows one to build outside the city boundary.

---

In my opinion, the current size of the map (16x16 HD buildings with streets between them) just needs to be doubled in both directions (32x32 HD buildings with streets between them).

Comment: It's kind of ironic. This Simcity is more of a downtown core simulator than a city simulator. Everything pushes you to upgrade vertically rather than have urban sprawl (HQs that increase in height, the progression of resource collection -> basic processing -> advanced manufacturing). So why is deleting/adding so buggy? (loss of vehicles/ roads overly aggressive binding to ploppables, etc.

Comment: Well, not everything... the tax system encourages sprawl.  The 0-maintenance roads encourage sprawl (relative to prior games).  The lost vehicles defect was introduced after launch, by some anti-exploit code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this guy is able to change the size of the map.

http://worldsims.org/playing-simcity-offline-with-azzeruk/3512/